# Parse entities referencing xml files in xml file (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser, domparser

I am using XML files to convey some data into my Android app, but as they get bigger, it's getting quite difficult to not get lost, so I wanted to split some part of it into smaller files. That is, in a first place I had something like :

guests.xml

```
<? ... ?>
<guests>
    <guest>
        <person>
            <name>Alice</name>
            <vegetarian>no</vegetarian>
            <drinks>everything</drinks>
        </person>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <person>
            <name>Bob</name>
            <vegetarian>ofcourse</vegetarian>
            <drinks>cocktails</drinks>
        </person>
    </guest>
</guests>
```

and would now like to have something like :

guests.xml

```
<? ... ?>
<!DOCTYPE guests [
<!ENTITY alice SYSTEM "alice.xml">
<!ENTITY bob SYSTEM "bob.xml">
]>

<guests>
    <guest>&alice;</guest>
    <guest>&bob;</guest>
</guests>
```

which is much more digest. Of course, alice.xml would be something around those lines:

```
<? ... ?>
<person>
    <name>Alice</name>
    <vegetarian>no</vegetarian>
    <drinks>everything</drinks>
</person>
```

So I tried to come up with something like that, using different tools, and unfortunately I didn't manage to get anywhere close to the goal. My first fail was using the DOMParser. It uses an "EntityResolver", which is an interface defined by the SAXParser tools. You implement it, override the function, and you return yourself the InputSource you want the parse to keep working on (if I understood correctly):

```
public class MyResolver implements EntityResolver {
    public InputSource resolveEntity (String publicId, String systemId){
    ...
    }
}
```

Now, it works topnotch in a regular Java environment, but in Android the function never gets called (I suspect some issue there). So I went on, and tried with the XmlPullParser (the recommended parser for Android). I never really liked the XmlPullParser (maybe because I just didn't take time to like it) but I got it working, at least without the entities. Unfortunately, it seems that I'm missing an important thing, and can't get what I want with the entities. If I'm correct, there are two modes for using a DTD :

1. Set the feature XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, and let the parser process the DTD itself. Then, it should read what is called the "replacement text" instead of the &..; entities.
2. Unset it, and take care of the DTD by yourself, using the method defineEntityReplacementText(String, String) which creates mappings between an entity name and its replacement text.

What bothers me is that the only replacement there could be is... text. So am I supposed to replace each entity by the whole content of the other XML file it is referring to? But then the parser won't see that as a file to parse, rather just some super long value for a give element.

Anyway, option 1.) just didn't work for me, as if the DTD is defined in the file itself (for instance like in guests.xml) I get an Exception if I don't use a keyword like "PUBLIC" or "SYSTEM". And if I do use "SYSTEM", the replacement text for a given entity is just null. If the DTD is defined in a file.dtd, all the replacement texts are just null Strings.

I didn't have the courage to try option 2., for I sense that once I filled all the needed entries in the "defineEntityReplacementText" map I will end up with just the same problem.

Does anybody see any reasoning mistake, or a workaround that doesn't involve creating my own 
    alice.xml
elements and parsing it by myself?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so what I eventually did is add an attribute "file" to the nodes that refer to external XML files, load them, and added some code to replace the node.

guests.xml :

```
<? ... ?>
<guests>
    <guest file="alice.xml"/>
    <guest file="bob.xml"/>
</guests>
```